# Functions that takes array as argument and generate random numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

First of all, any of *built-in methods cannot be used*. ex. `pop()`, `shift()`. What I can use is merely loops, array and so on.

I would like to make a function which takes an array as an argument and generate random strings of numbers, which does not contain these numbers given in the array.

For instance, `func([6, 2]) //=> "20353"` (2 and 6 would not be there).
The array length could change (`[6, 2, 9]`, `[7, 2, 1, 9]`). So the function has to have an ability to accommodate any length of an array.

In order to tackle this practice question, I have used `for` and `while` loops. However, I ran into a problem that, when the second index is checked (whether numbers randomly generated contain 2 or not, in the example), if it contains, I regenerate the random number and it could produce the first index number (in this case, 6) which I do not want.

Please see the code I posted below and help me solve this. On top of that, if there is another way to get the same result which is a better way, please let me know too.

```js
let str = "";
let arr = [];
let tem

const func = arg2 => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let v = 0; v < arg2.length; v++) {
      if (arg2[v] == arr[i]) {
        do {
          tem = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        } while (tem == arr[i])
        arr[i] = tem;
      }
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) str += arr[i]
  return str
}

console.log(func([6, 2]))

// the output will not contain 2, which is the last index element
// however, when the second index number is removed, the output might replace it with 6, which is the first index element
```

Expected output:

```
func([6, 3, 8]) //=> "45102"
func([4, 9]) //=> "55108"
```

Comment: The length of the string result should always be 5?

Comment: *"any of built-in methods cannot be used."*: you are already using two native methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're overthinking this. The basic algorithm is:

- In a loop:

  - If *output* has 5 digits, return it.
  - Otherwise

    - Pick a random digit *n* from 0 to 9.
    - If *n* is **not** in the list of excluded numbers, it to *output*.

This maps pretty directly to the following function:

```js
function fn(exclude, length = 5) {
  let output = '';
  while (output.length < length) {
    const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    if (!exclude.includes(n)) {
      output += n;
    }
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(fn([6,3,8]));
```

There are, of course, other ways to achieve this, such as initializing an array with five elements and then `join`ing the elements:

```js
function fn(exclude, length = 5) {
  return Array.from({ length }, () => {
    let n;
    while (n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10), exclude.includes(n)) {}
    return n;
  }).join('');
}

console.log(fn([6,3,8]));
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you already use two native methods (`floor` and `random`), but I'll assume you're OK with that.

Secondly, in your question the term *digit* would have been more appropriate in some instances than *number*. There is a difference...

To avoid that you still select a digit that is not allowed, you could first build an array with digits that are still allowed, and then randomly pick values from *that* array. That way you will not ever pick a wrong one.

Here is how that would look:

```js
const func = arg2 => {
    const digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    // Mark digits that are not allowed with -1
    for (let i=0; i<arg2.length; i++) {
        digits[arg2[i]] = -1;
    }
    // Collect digits that are still allowed
    const allowed = [];
    for (let i=0; i<digits.length; i++) {
        if (digits[i] > -1) allowed[allowed.length] = digits[i];
    }
    // Pick random digits from the allowed digits
    let str = "";
    for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
        str += allowed[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)];
    }
    return str;
}

console.log(func([6, 2]));
```

Just for fun, if you lift the restrictions on what language aspects cannot be used, you can do this as follows:

```js
const func = arg2 => {
    const digits = new Set(Array(10).keys());
    for (let digit of arg2) digits.delete(digit);
    const allowed = [...digits];
    return Array.from({length:5}, () => 
        allowed[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)]
    ).join``;
}

console.log(func([6, 2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the entire `arg2` array each time you pick a random digit. You can't replace the value in the `arg2` loop, because then you won't check against earlier elements.

You don't need the `arr` array, you can append to `str` in the loop.

```js
const func = arg2 => {
  let str = "";
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let random;
    while (true) {
      let ok = true;
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      for (let j = 0; j < arg2.length; j++) {
        if (random == arg2[j]) {
          ok = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (ok) {
        break;
      }
    }
    str += random
  }

  return str
}

console.log(func([6, 2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact (what others stated as well) that you use native array-methods yourself, I would probably go for it with something like this (using only what you used so far):

```js
const func = without => {
    let result = '';

    while (result.length < 5) {
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        let add = true;

        for (i=0; i<without.length; i++) {
            if (rand === without[i]) {
                add = false;
            }
        }

        if (add) {
            result += rand;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(func([6, 2]))
```

a more concise version using native array methods could look like this:

```js
const func = without => {
    let result = '';

    while (result.length < 5) {
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

        if (!without.includes(rand)) {
            result += rand;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(func([6, 2]))
```